# PayPal Express Checkout: can I count on the PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ADDRESSSTATUS value?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

Customers on my site choose their shipping address which I send to PayPal.
now I want to make sure that the shipping address they've chosen is confirmed.

Can I count on the value of PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ADDRESSSTATUS field?
Does PayPal checks the input shipping address against their shipping addresses?

10x

Answer (score 0):

Yes your understanding is correct.

Please refer more here:
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetExpressCheckoutDetails_API_Operation_NVP/

Comment: I'm doing the same operation, following the same logic, and Paypal just add the address I submitted (For verification purpose) to the user addresses as an "Alternate address".. Which ALWAYS comes back as [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ADDRESSSTATUS] => Confirmed.. Any clues?